# Probability independent events 3

Tags: probability

Events $A$
 and $B$
 are independent. Suppose event $A$
 occurs with probability 0.05
 and event $B$
 occurs with probability 0.70.

1.Compute the probability that $A$
 occurs but $B$
 does not occur.

2.Compute the probability that either $B$
 occurs without $A$
 occurring or $A$
 and $B$
 both occur.

now that the events are independent 
My answer for no.1= P(A)*P(B)=0.05*0.70=0.035

2.P(BUA')∩P(BUA)=(P(B)*P(A')) ∩ (P(B)*P(A))

```
            =(0.70*0.95) ∩ (0.70*0.05) 
            =0.665+0.035-(0.665*0.035)
            =0.676725
```

is it correct?

Comment: In the first question, you forgot to take into account that $B$ does NOT occur. And the second question is fairly easy, it's just "B and not A or B and A"

Comment: You mean for no.2 is it P(BUA')∩P(BUA)?

Comment: P(BUA')∩P(BUA)=(P(B)*P(A')) ∩ (P(B)*P(A))
                            =(0.70*0.95) ∩  (0.70*0.05)
                            =0.665+0.035-(0.665*0.035)
                            =0.676725     Am I correct?

Comment: Actually in the second question, it doesn't matter whether $A$ occurs. The answer is just the probability of $B$.

Comment: I think you have the symbols for intersection and union mixed up in your first comment.

Comment: I am sorry I don't get it, could you please elaborate more?

Comment: Could you please just tell me the final answer for both 1 and 2, i will try to find out the steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $$
  P(A\text{ and }\neg B)=P(A)P(\neg B) = P(A)(1-P(B)) = 0.05 \times (1-0.7) = 0.015
  $$
- $$
  \begin{split}
  P([\neg A\text{ and }B ]\text{ or }[A \text{ and } B]) &= P(\neg A\text{ and }B )+ P(A \text{ and } B) \\ &= (1-P(A))P(B) + P(A)P(B)\\ &= P(B) \\&= 0.7
  \end{split}
  $$

Comment: How to solve this if the event A and B is mutually exclusive?

Comment: Do you mean if $A \Leftrightarrow \neg B$?

Comment: Events A and B are mutually exclusive. Suppose event A occurs with probability 0.74 and event B occurs with probability 0.22.

1.Compute the probability that A occurs but B does not occur.

2.Compute the probability that either A occurs without B occurring or A and B both occur.

Answer for 1. P(A and ¬B)=P(A)+P(¬B)-P(A∩B)=0.74+0.78-(0.74*0.78)=0.9428
2.P([¬B and A] or [A and B])=P(¬B and A)+P(A and B)=0.78*0.74+0.74*0.22=0.74

Is it correct?